# why does clocking into org mode task in one file require a network connection for different, tramp-connected file?

Tags: org-mode, tramp

I have several files listed as org agenda files, one of which is loaded via ssh using tramp. I do all my time tracking in a different file, which is local to my computer. But when I don't have a network connection, tramp gets upset when I try to clock into a task in the local file.  I get:

```
Tramp: Opening connection nil for remotemachine using plinkx...
Tramp failed to connect.  If this happens repeatedly, try
‘M-x tramp-cleanup-this-connection’
Tramp: Opening connection nil for remotemachine using plinkx...failed
```

This doesn't seem to make sense. Why can't org handle this situation? How I can tell it to just clock in without re-loading all other agenda files?